# 2sat approximation related problem.

Tags: computational-complexity

Let $ { L }_{ \varepsilon   }$ to be the language of all 2CNF formulas $\varphi $, such that at least $(\frac { 1 }{ 2 } + \varepsilon  )$ of $\varphi$ 's clauses can be satisfied. 
Prove that there exists ${ \varepsilon   }' > 0$ s.t. ${ L }_{ \varepsilon   }$ is NP-hard for any $\varepsilon  <\varepsilon  '$.

I know that $gap-2SAT\left[ \frac { 3 }{ 4 } ,1 \right]$  is in P thus $\frac { 3 }{ 4 }$ -approximation of max2SAT is in P, so if i chose very small constant $\varepsilon$ such that $\frac { 1 }{ 2 } <\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\varepsilon <\frac { 3 }{ 4 } $ then the statement above is wrong(there is no such ${ \varepsilon   }'$).

Any help would be appreciated.